# I need some help in splitting an eccesive value into following rows

Tags: mysql

I need some help in this logic:
I have a table created like this:

[image]

I need an SQL where I calculate a New ImpegnoSlot based on this logic:

each row cannot have a column impegno higher than settings.MaxImpegno (in this example will be 3), so I need a select where the eccessive quantity is added to the following rows up to 3, like this (not working)

```
SELECT p.IdSlot, 
   p.Orario, 
   p.ImpegnoSlot,
   IF(p.NewImpegno < s.MaxImpegnoForno, p.ImpegnoSlot, p.NewImpegno) as ImpegnoNew FROM (SELECT es.*,               
           ( es.ImpegnoSlot + 
             (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(es2.ImpegnoSlot - s.MaxImpegnoForno), 0)
                FROM elenco_slot es2,
                     settings s
               WHERE es2.Orario < es.Orario
                 AND (es2.ImpegnoSlot - s.MaxImpegnoForno) > 0
              ORDER BY es2.orario)
           ) as NewImpegno
     FROM elenco_slot es
    WHERE 1 = 1
    ORDER BY es.orario) p,
   settings s ORDER BY p.Orario
```

What I need is this:

[image]

Can anybody help?
thank you

EDIT 1:

I'm providing table data as text:

```
1   15:00:00    0.00
2   15:15:00    0.00
3   15:30:00    0.00
4   15:45:00    0.00
5   16:00:00    0.00
6   16:15:00    0.00
7   16:30:00    0.00
8   16:45:00    0.00
9   17:00:00    6.00
10  17:15:00    1.00
11  17:30:00    1.00
12  17:45:00    0.00
13  18:00:00    0.00
14  18:15:00    0.00
15  18:30:00    0.00
16  18:45:00    0.00
17  19:00:00    0.00
18  19:15:00    0.00
19  19:30:00    0.00
20  19:45:00    0.00
21  20:00:00    0.00
23  20:15:00    0.00
24  20:30:00    0.00
25  20:45:00    0.00
26  21:00:00    0.00
27  21:15:00    0.00
28  21:30:00    0.00
29  21:45:00    0.00
30  22:00:00    0.00
31  22:15:00    0.00
32  22:30:00    0.00
33  22:45:00    0.00
34  23:00:00    0.00
35  23:15:00    0.00
36  23:30:00    0.00
37  23:45:00    0.00
```

And also expected result as text

```
4   15:45:00    0.00    0.00
5   16:00:00    0.00    0.00
6   16:15:00    0.00    0.00
7   16:30:00    0.00    0.00
8   16:45:00    0.00    0.00
9   17:00:00    6.00    6.00
10  17:15:00    1.00    3.00
11  17:30:00    1.00    2.00
12  17:45:00    0.00    0.00
13  18:00:00    0.00    0.00
14  18:15:00    0.00    0.00
15  18:30:00    0.00    0.00
16  18:45:00    0.00    0.00
17  19:00:00    0.00    0.00
18  19:15:00    0.00    0.00
19  19:30:00    0.00    0.00
20  19:45:00    0.00    0.00
21  20:00:00    0.00    0.00
23  20:15:00    0.00    0.00
24  20:30:00    0.00    0.00
25  20:45:00    0.00    0.00
26  21:00:00    0.00    0.00
27  21:15:00    0.00    0.00
28  21:30:00    0.00    0.00
29  21:45:00    0.00    0.00
30  22:00:00    0.00    0.00
31  22:15:00    0.00    0.00
32  22:30:00    0.00    0.00
33  22:45:00    0.00    0.00
34  23:00:00    0.00    0.00
35  23:15:00    0.00    0.00
36  23:30:00    0.00    0.00
37  23:45:00    0.00    0.00
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expect results by text instead of an image? thanks

Comment: I have added it in the main question

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: version is 8.0.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method uses a variable and should work in all versions of mySQL.
Following the request I have added a second version with a parameter for the max value. See after the first version.

> ```
> create table settings(
> id int not null primary key auto_increment,
> imp int);
> insert into settings (imp)
> values
> (0),(0),(6),(1),(1),(0);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> set @c = 0;
> select
>   id,
>   imp raw_value,
>   case when imp + @c > 2 
>     then 3 else imp + @c end smoothed_value,
>   @c := case 
>     when (imp + @c) > 2 
>       then imp + @c - 3
>     else 0 end calculation
> FROM settings
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> id | raw_value | smoothed_value | calculation
> -: | --------: | -------------: | ----------:
>  1 |         0 |              0 |           0
>  2 |         0 |              0 |           0
>  3 |         6 |              3 |           3
>  4 |         1 |              3 |           1
>  5 |         1 |              2 |           0
>  6 |         0 |              0 |           0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f53c9a0bece7997dc7150f122b341f45)*

> ```
> create table settings(
> id int not null primary key auto_increment,
> imp int);
> insert into settings (imp)
> values
> (0),(0),(36),(1),(8),(0),(0),(0);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> set @max = 10;
> set @c = 0;
> select
>   id,
>   imp raw_value,
>   case when imp + @c > @max 
>     then @max else imp + @c end smoothed_value,
>   @c := case 
>     when (imp + @c) > @max 
>       then imp + @c - @max
>     else 0 end carry_over_to_next_line
> FROM settings
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> id | raw_value | smoothed_value | carry_over_to_next_line
> -: | --------: | -------------: | ----------------------:
>  1 |         0 |              0 |                       0
>  2 |         0 |              0 |                       0
>  3 |        36 |             10 |                      26
>  4 |         1 |             10 |                      17
>  5 |         8 |             10 |                      15
>  6 |         0 |             10 |                       5
>  7 |         0 |              5 |                       0
>  8 |         0 |              0 |                       0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fe0ecad0e32ffb6450c18f6e71c4e57f)*

Comment: Thanks!! I'm not sure I understand why, but it works. I have a question though. What is 3 and what is 2? Now it works because I have said each value must not be greater than 3. What if I need 10 maximum? How should I change it?

Comment: I've added a second version using a parameter for the maximum value and changed the name of the 3rd column to make it clearer.